# ReactJS : How to pass values material ui for complex json structure

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In material UI [GRID](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/) how to access complex object

Suppose I need to access the `ami_info.account` if I do this it just displays Undefined in the UI.

```
var columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 90,  },
    {
        field: 'ami_info',
        headerName: 'ami_info',
        width: 160,
        valueGetter: (params) =>
            `${params.getValue('ami_info.account')}`
    },
];
```

The JSON

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "ami_info":{
      "id":0,
      "profile":"default",
      "account":"506521206092"
    },
    "instance_id":"id-e223114",
    "CommandOutputs":[
      {
        "Stdout":"Out",
        "Stderr":"Error",
        "ExitCode":1
      },
      {
        "Stdout":"Out",
        "Stderr":"Error",
        "ExitCode":1
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

what should I do to access the array of Objects? `CommandOutputs`  in the DataGrid

All my failed Tried

`${params.getValue('ami_info.id.account')}`
`${params.getValue('ami_info.account')}`

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Material UI DataGrid, but looking at their example code, the params.getValue() method takes a params.id parameter before the field name parameter. You're not including this params.id in your code above - is there a reason why? Have you tried this?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the object values after getting it

```
var columns = [
    { field: 'id', headerName: 'ID', width: 90,  },
    {
        field: 'ami_info',
        headerName: 'ami_info',
        width: 160,
        valueGetter: (params) =>
            `${params.getValue('ami_info').account}`
    },
];
```

Comment: Doesn't work any other suggestion to tried out

Comment: Try `params.getValue(params.id, 'ami_info').account`

Comment: Check it https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-5fnm8

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'account' of undefined @iunfixit